# PHP redirect to another domain like biltly.com without hurting SEO (based on user-agent)

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

My Url format is

> `http://example.com/page_url?utm_compaign=abc&domain=new_domain.com&any_param=any_value`

I want to extract domain name from query parameter "domain" and send the visitor to new url like

> `http://new_domain.com/page_url&utm_compaign=abc&any_param=any_value`

I know how to parse Url & redirect in PHP.

Here is my simple PHP code.

```
    header('HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently');
    header('Location: ' . htmlspecialchars_decode($new_url, ENT_NOQUOTES));
```

I want to make sure that it wouldn't hurt SEO and target domain new_domain.com properly gets client browser user-agent and client referring domain.

For example if client/user browser is at domain abc.com and he/she clicks on link LINK-1 then final target domain where user is being redirected should get proper referring domain abc.com in Google Analytic and there is no clue of intermediate domain example.com like bitly.com does.

Furthermore, I want to extract user-agent in the intermediate domain using PHP and if user-agent matches my string, I want them to add some extra query parameters or do some task then allow or block the redirection.

Some code like

```
if $client-user-agent = "my-user-agent-string" 
{ do-some-task-and-stop-redirect-or-just-show-some-message();
} else {
 redirect();
}
```

I hope I have explained my problem well if there is any confusion in the question please ask.

I want to develop a solution like link shortner services bilty.com or goo.gl do. Domain example.com and new_domain.com are under my control but domain abc.com is not, where links will be placed or come from.

Thanks.

Comment: I am unable to solve. If you have some time please help me to solve it. @Machavity